# Chrome cookie Created: & Expires: time 2 hours previous

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

Alternate question: What does chrome use for clock settings?

While developing and testing a 30 minute cookie, I discovered that Chrome declares the cookie was created 2 hours earlier and will expire 2 hours earlier than computer time.

Maybe a picture will help with the details. This is not just related to the development site. For example, I visited SO at 8:22 am local time (US/East) and macbook's clock. According to Chrome, two cookies were set at 6:22am. (Both the laptop and I were still sleeping at that time.)

Gmail timezone is set to US/East.

Any ideas if this is intended, incorrect setting or a possible bug?

[image: Chrome cookie display]

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @DhananjayanSanthanakrishnan  No, I have not.  I gave up looking for a solution.

Comment: Did you try MaxAge? I settled down with that for now.

Comment: I have same problem; Also tried max-age and the result is same